# Winsock connection to bluetooth device fails when using a Bluetooth 5.0 dongle

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, winsock

I am currently using this code to discover, then start up a connection with a bluetooth device using the winsock2 API:

```cpp
  constexpr BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS btDeviceSearchParameters = {
      sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
      1,
      0,
      1,
      1,
      1,
      2,
      nullptr
  };

  BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO btDeviceInfo = {sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO), {0}};
  const HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND btDevice =
      BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&btDeviceSearchParameters, &btDeviceInfo);

  if (btDevice == nullptr) {
    printf("Could not find any bluetooth devices");
    *addr = NULL;
    return false;
  }

  const auto thiswstring = std::wstring(btSerialConfiguration_.name.begin(), btSerialConfiguration_.name.end());
  const WCHAR* wcDeviceName = const_cast<WCHAR*>(thiswstring.c_str());

  do {
    if (wcscmp(btDeviceInfo.szName, wcDeviceName) == 0) {
      printf("A Device found");
      if (btDeviceInfo.fAuthenticated)
      {
        printf("Bluetooth Device authenticated");
        *addr = btDeviceInfo.Address.ullLong;
        return true;
      } else {
        printf("Bluetooth device not authenticated");
      }
    }
  } while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(btDevice, &btDeviceInfo));


  btClientSocket_ = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);

  SOCKADDR_BTH btSocketAddress{};
  btSocketAddress.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
  btSocketAddress.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID;
  btSocketAddress.port = 0;
  btSocketAddress.btAddr = addr;

  if (connect(btClientSocket_, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&btSocketAddress), sizeof btSocketAddress) != 0)  // connect to the BT device.
  {
    printf("Failed to connect to bluetooth device");
    return false;
  }
```

I previously had a 4.0 bluetooth dongle, and using this dongle I was successfully able to connect to the device with this code and start receiving data from it.

However, after switching to a 5.0 dongle, this is no longer the case, and when the call to `connect()` is made, I receive this error: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Is there something that I am missing to get a connection going when using a 5.0 bluetooth dongle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your service class is invalid.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Would you be able to point me in the direction to a valid one to use? Thanks

Comment: SerialPortServiceClass_UUID

Comment: @MikePetrichenko this results in the same error unfortunately. Is there anything else you can spot which I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are lot of reasons. Probably device requires authentication, probably bad dongle. Would be great to see the error code, not the description.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I receive the "Bluetooth Device authenticated" logline, so I assume it's authenticated? Might be wrong though. The error code is 10060. Thanks

Comment: The error is WSAETIMEDOUT. So its timeout. However this error may appear in case if device requires authentication and it was started but no one side provides authentication data (PIN, Confirmation, other, depends on requirements).

Comment: @MikePetrichenko thanks for the clarification - I tried to authenticate the BluetoothAuthenticateDevice but I receive an error that it is already authenticated. Do you by any chance have any other suggestions?

Comment: You did not request authentication for connection. It does no tmatter if the device already paired, you must request authentication for connection.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko please could you point me in the direction of documentation for how to do this? Also, would authentication differ between bluetooth 4.0 dongle and 5.0 dongles? It seems strange that it works for 4.0 dongles but not 5.0. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-socket-options

Comment: @MikePetrichenko This is the code I'm trying:  ```if (setsockopt(btClientSocket_, SOL_RFCOMM, SO_BTH_AUTHENTICATE, (char*)&dwOptVal, sizeof(DWORD)) == 0) {
    LogMessage("Success setting socket option");
  }```, which still results in timeout

Comment: Run RFCOMM server on one PC and RFCOMM client on other to make sure dongle works as expected. Or use Android cell with GPS2BLUE application (server) and RFCOMM client on PC. You can use RfCommClient and RfCommServer from our product to make it faster (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). If it will work then problem is in your device. If it will not work - the problem is in dongle.